# Stat Tracking of Customized data

Tags: statistics, google-analytics, analytics

I feel like I've been all over the web for this but haven't found anything like what I'm looking for, I might just be using the wrong keywords.

Basically I need a stat tracking system which allows me to track a variety of different types of events, each of them connected to a user that has custom properties (id, country, etc). Think Google Analytics with custom events and custom variables, but without the limit of 5 custom variables and more flexibility with events.

The events are anything from impressions to bank statuses and item ownerships. Basically our database in a statistical format.

At the moment we simply use our MySQL database to gather the info we need, but as we are rapidly growing we cannot keep doing this, also we really need a system that can automate the creation of statistical reports.

So my question really comes down to this, are there any such services (preferrably open source) out there, or possibly frameworks or databases created especially for this type of processing that we can easily create our own stat tracking software from?

Long story short, I need a service, framework or database that eases the creation of custom statistics reports.

Any help would be much appreciated. Apologies if this is not supposed to be on Stackoverflow, I wasn't sure where else to ask this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[R](https://www.r-project.org/) is a free re-implementation of the S statistics language, and is very popular, especially for those who are looking for a heavy-duty statistics programming language.

[SPSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPSS) is more desktop-software oriented; it was the tool we used in my statistics courses a decade ago, and would probably still be the king of desktop software analysis tools for traditional statistics work.

[NumPy](https://numpy.org/) is a numerical analysis tool for Python. (A fellow stacker has pointed out a website that has a lot of comparisons of Python with R that might be useful to helping you decide between them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489466/list-of-r-python-equivalents/6493539#6493539.) I'm not sure how well it fits with general statistics works, but it is very popular in a wide array of sciences.

[Tableau Software](https://www.tableau.com/) has some tools that a friend speaks very highly about -- I've just skimmed their literature, and it looks like they might make *exploring* data easier, but traditional analysis of statistics might not be their strongest point.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I should clarify that in terms of frameworks and databases I'm looking for something that has the capacity to process a LARGE amount of entries. It's not so much about what tools I have at my disposal to achieve this, just that the system running them has the ability to do it relatively fast.

Comment: Tableau Server looks awesome and exactly what we need. Unfortunately I don't think I'll be able to convince my boss on the price tag at this point :( Any cheaper / open source alternatives?

Comment: @Naatan, any luck finding anything like an open-source Tableau?

Comment: Nope, haven't found anything useful. Decided on creating our own stats system instead, cheaper than paying for a Tableau license. Go figure.

Comment: @Nataan, thanks for the feedback. Pity, I'd like to at least know a similar tool that'd run on my platform of choice... :)